# TableViewのスクロールに合わせてCollectionViewをスクロールさせたい

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

TableViewの下にCollectionViewを配置し、

**<やりたいこと>**

**1 TableViewをスクロールさせるとCollectionViewがスクロール** 
(tableViewのセクションindexをとって、collectionViewではそのindexのitemに移動。例えば、tableView section indexが3であれば、collectionViewのセクション1のitem index3に移動)

**2 CollectionViewをスクロールするとTableViewがスクロール**

という動作をさせたく、下記のようなコードを書きました。

**<問題>**

2はうまく動いたのですが、1がうまく動きません。

7行目でブレイクポイントを張ったところ、collectionViewIndexPathはうまく取得できているのですが、collectionViewCellが微動だにしません。

どのようにしたら、うまく動くようになるでしょうか。アドバイスいただけたら幸いです。

**スクリーンショット**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**コード**

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView == tableView{
        let sectionIndex =  self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows![0].section
        if self.collectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(1) >= sectionIndex {
            let collectionViewIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sectionIndex, inSection: 1)
            self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(collectionViewIndexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
        }
    }

    if scrollView == collectionView {
        let itemIndex = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems()[1].item //{
        if self.tableView.numberOfSections > itemIndex {
            let tableViewIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: itemIndex)
            self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(tableViewIndexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

**Viewの構造**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**環境**

Xcode 7.1 / BaseSDK iOS9.1 / Swift 2.1
Deployment Target iOS8.2
MacOS X 10.11.1(El Capitan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

他の場所でアドバイスをいただき、解決しました。

このプログラムでは、collectionViewを水平方向に動かしたいので、atScrollPosition: .Topではダメで、.Right .Left .CenteredHorizontally などにしないといけないようでした。

私の場合は、該当セルを真ん中に置きたいので、.CenteredHorizontally にしたらうまく動きました。